# Traefik - Can't connect via https

Tags: https, traefik

I am trying to run Traefik on a Raspberry Pi Docker Swarm (specifally following this guide https://github.com/openfaas/faas/blob/master/guide/traefik_integration.md from the OpenFaaS project) but have run into some trouble when actually trying to connect via https.

Specifically there are two issues:

1) When I connect to http://192.168.1.20/ui I am given the username / password prompt.  However the details (unhashed password) generated by htpasswd and used in the below docker-compose.yml are not accepted.

2) Visting the https version (http://192.168.1.20/ui) does not connect at all.  This is the same if I try to connect using the domain I have set in `--acme.domains`

When I explore `/etc/` I can see that no `/etc/traefik/` directory exists but should presumably be created so perhaps this is the root of my problem?

The relevant part of my `docker-compose.yml` looks like

```
traefik:
    image: traefik:v1.3
    command: -c --docker=true
        --docker.swarmmode=true
        --docker.domain=traefik
        --docker.watch=true
        --web=true
        --debug=true
        --defaultEntryPoints=https,http
        --acme=true
        --acme.domains='<my domain>'
        --acme.email=myemail@gmail.com
        --acme.ondemand=true
        --acme.onhostrule=true
        --acme.storage=/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json
        --entryPoints=Name:https Address::443 TLS
        --entryPoints=Name:http Address::80 Redirect.EntryPoint:https
    ports:
        - 80:80
        - 8080:8080
        - 443:443
    volumes:
        - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
        - "acme:/etc/traefik/acme"
    networks:
        - functions
    deploy:
        labels:
            - traefik.port=8080
            - traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/ui,/system,/function
            - traefik.frontend.auth.basic=user:password  <-- relevant credentials from htpasswd here
        restart_policy:
            condition: on-failure
            delay: 5s
            max_attempts: 20
            window: 380s
        placement:
            constraints: [node.role == manager]

volumes:
  acme:
```

Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/2018-01-09-issue-with-tls-sni-01-and-shared-hosting-infrastructure/49996

The TLS challenge (default) for Let's Encrypt doesn't work anymore.

You must use the DNS challenge instead https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/acme/#dnsprovider.

Or waiting for the merge of https://github.com/containous/traefik/pull/2701